# How do I symlink this file?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

I'm really confused.  I'm trying to install rvm ( Ruby's version manager ) but keep getting an error message.  Something about how `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt not found`.  I believe the security certificates are located in /etc/ssl/.... on Ubuntu.  So I tried something like

```
ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

but that did not work.  I get an error message that I'm not able to create that symbolic link.  Could someone explain how I can do that?  I also tried to compile (from source) Ruby 2.3.  It worked and most of the Ruby files work just fine, but when I enter

```
require "openssl"
```

I get an error message that the file is not available.  I suspect the same problem is happening and I'll have to recompile Ruby so that it "knows" that my security certificates are in `/etc/ssl/certs/` and NOT in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/`.

Comment: did you try to create the link using `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will need to be root to do something in `/etc/...`.

Try

```
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```